# Anchor IDL type for structs

Tags: pda, idl

I'm trying to fetch a PDA account and use one of it's properties as a seed for another PDA account. Here's what the implementation looks like:

```
const [ registryPDA, registryBump ] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([Buffer.from('REGISTRY')], PROGRAM_KEY);
const registry = await program.account["registry"].fetch(registryPDA);
const company_id = registry.totalCompanies.toArrayLike(Buffer, "be", 8);

const [ companyPDA, companyBump ] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([Buffer.from('COMPANY'), company_id], PROGRAM_KEY);
```

but it gives an error for `registry.totalCompanies`: `'registry.totalCompanies' is of type 'unknown'` 
It seems like since registry variable is type of unknown, it can't figure out how to turn it into Buffer. How can I specify it's account type?

Answer (score 0):

I was declaring the program as:

```
const program = new Program(IDL as Idl, PROGRAM_KEY, provider)
```

But I was able to use the IdlType anchor created in types/.ts and solve the error by declaring program as:

```
const program = new Program(IDL as Main, PROGRAM_KEY, provider)
```